# Is it wrong to put exclamation mark (!) after 'Thanks'?

Tags: punctuation

Is the following approach wrong?

> ***Thanks!*** for the LIC receipt. I am good. How are you?

Is it ok to put an exclamation mark after 'Thanks'?

Comment: That looks wrong to me.  I'd write "Thanks for the LIC receipt!".  But I'm not 100% sure about the technical rules for this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A comma can take place of an interjection when expressing a weaker emotion and exclamation when expressing a stronger emotion. But, as far as I know, neither of them is correct in your case as the sentence is not independent.

Example:

> Thanks! I am fine.
>
> Thanks, but I am fine.
>
> Thanks. I am fine.
>
> No, it's not yours. (weaker emotion.)
>
> No! it's not yours. (Stronger emotion.)
>
> Thanks, John. (A comma is used here because I am addressing someone directly, but I am offsetting a name here, not the interjection.)
>
> Well, the rain has played its part in the outcome of this match.

The following examples are wrong:

> Thanks! **for** the offer.
>
> Thanks, **for** the offer.

Why? Read the next section. :)

---

Now coming back to your question

> Thanks! for the LIC receipt. I am good. How are you?

Here, ***For the LIC receipt*** is not a complete sentence and, hence, cannot stand on its own.

A better approach as provided by @mamtaD is:

> Thanks! I got the LIC receipt. I am good. How are you?

She is right in her own sense, but this changes the meaning of the sentence. It is interesting to note that "thanks" is not used as an interjection, but as a verb(in OP's case).

A much better approach is to either put an exclamation mark at the end of the sentence or to avoid punctuating around the verb *thanks.*

> - Thanks for the LIC receipt! I am good. How are you?(expressing strong emotion)
> - Thanks for the LIC receipt. I am good. How are you?

Comment: You could also write "I got the receipt - thanks!" I like keeping the exclamation point next to thanks to make it clear that's what I'm emphasizing, not receiving the receipt. The dash is informal, but I think it's fine given the context. Punctuation is just a tool to make your meaning clear after all ;)

Answer (score 2):

As the second part of the sentence following `Thanks` is not a complete sentence on its own, it's incorrect here in this case. A better way of writing would be

> Thanks! I got the LIC receipt. I am good. How are you?

For a detailed guide on how/when to use exclamation marks, check [here](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/punctuation/when/when-to-use-exclamation-marks.html).

If you want to **emphasize** the interjection (Thanks), the exclamation should be placed immediately after the word.

Comment: How about 'Thanks for sending the LIC receipt!'?

Comment: That would work too, however, there is less emphasis on the first word. If you want to emphasize the interjection (Thanks), the exclamation should be placed immediately after the word.